# Convert a MMM yyyy string date to a DateTime value without a massive nested if using c#?

Tags: c#, datetime, date-conversion

I have an incoming string variable called strDate that's formatted with the first three characters of the month and a four character year, like this: "Jul 2017".

I need to convert that string to a date formatted like this: "7/1/2017". I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this than creating a massive nested if along the pattern shown below to account for all 12 months. I hate repeating code. Can anyone make a suggestion?

```
string strDate = "Jul 2017";
string strNewDate = "";

if (strDate.Substring(0,3) == "Jul")
{
    string strMonth = "7";
    strNewDate = strMonth + "/1/";
    strNewDate = strNewDate + strDate.Substring(4, 4);
    DateTime newDate = Convert.ToDateTime(strNewDate);
}
```

Comment: `DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, "MMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to do a `DateTime.TryParse()`:

```
string input = "Jul 2017";      
DateTime newDateTime;
if(DateTime.TryParse(input, out newDateTime ))
{
    //newDateTime was parsed successfully
}
```

Your format ("MMM yyyy") is a standard format that C# recognizes to it should parse fine.  However there is the `DateTime.TryParseExact` method that lets you specify the **exact** format you are expecting the string to be in.

Comment: And if you know the string is going to be a valid date, you can just use `var dateValue = DateTime.Parse("Jul 2017");`

Comment: Bingo! I'm brand new to c# so I'm not familiar with all these nifty commands. But your solution is spot on and works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help

Comment: finish with res.ToShortDateString() to see formatted date

Comment: Rufus, I do know that the string will always be a valid date because it's generated by code. I really like your even more simplified suggestion with just one line of code. Thanks!

Comment: @csharpMind its typically good practice not to always assume its in the right format, just because sometimes things are out of your control.  Using `TryParse` is quicker than wrapping a `Parse` in a `try/catch`

Comment: @maccettura That's good advice. Thanks for reminding of that best practice.